# Is it possible to change the position of a p5 text element after it is drawn?

Tags: p5.js

Can you change the position of a p5 text element after it is draw without redrawing the entire canvas? If so, how would I be able to?
I'm trying to make text appear under players set to their current position, but when they move I want it to change its position to the player's position. I have the events with that setup, I just don't know how to change the position of the element.

Comment: you should post your attempt. there are at least two options: 1. when you call `text("yourText", x, y);` you can use the player's x, y position with an offset to text is under the player, 2. you could use `push()`/`pop()` to "group" the player and text rendering in a single coordinate space so the text is always relative to the player

Comment: The answer to this question is trivially found by simply reading the documentation: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text

Comment: @PaulWheeler I looked at the docs and all I found was AlignText. The problem with that is that I cant make it go to specific x and y coords.

Comment: There is no "AlignText" in p5.js, and if you take a minute to actually read the documentation that I linked to, which is for the `text()` function you will see that it takes three parameters which are clearly documented in the Parameters section: str (the string to be rendered), x, and y which are the horizontal and vertical position of the text. The `textAlign` function (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/textAlign) configured how the text is positioned relative to the specified x, y coordinates.

Comment: @PaulWheeler What I'm trying to find out, is how to change the text's position after it has been set. So the idea would be like text.move(x,y) or something like that.

Comment: Finally, we get to the heart of the matter. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some libraries, such as [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), graphical elements in p5.js are not persistent objects that can be moved or modified once they are drawn. Instead, everything in p5.js is drawn in [immediate mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)). So when you are drawing text you specify it's attributes at the time you draw it, using the [Typography functions](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-Typography), and the [`text()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text). In order to "move" text you would clear the canvas, or re-paint the background (using `clear()` or [`background()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear) respectively, and then re-drawing the text with different settings or parameters.